# MySQL TLS verification via OpenSSL Fails

Tags: mysql, ssl, openssl, tls1.2

I have my MySQL instance configured to use TLS. I have verified this by intentionally using untrusted certificates and watching the clients fail to connect (with an appropriate error message) and then restarting the MySQL service with trusted certificates configured and having the clients connect successfully.

I wanted to do a final check using openssl's s_client but I can't get it to work. When I execute the command below, I get an error saying "SSL23_GET_SERVER_Hello:unknown protocol" followed by "no peer certificate available" followed by some more text. However, when I use the same command against a TLS-enabled Tomcat instance and against the Remote Desktop port, I am able to establish the connection and view the server's certificate. What am I doing wrong? Does MySQL do some extra pre-negotiation before the TLS handshake starts?

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect host:port
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While MySQL may use TLS, it isn't the total outside layer. There is a small amount of preamble that occurs before TLS starts. The openssl command line isn't aware of this.

Use the mysql client with its TLS options to test the client certificate.

Answer (score 0):

I marked the response from @danblack correct as he did answer the question. However, I want to provide more information in case it helps anyone else. The

> small amount of preamble that occurs before TLS starts

that he refers to can be found on GitHub [here](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-j/blob/34cbc6bc61f72836e26327537a432d6db7c77de6/src/main/protocol-impl/java/com/mysql/cj/protocol/a/NativeProtocol.java#L349).